# Realm database set up with Objective-C to Swift Bridging

Tags: realm

I have an older project with Realms Objective-C database setup. I am working on converting most of the project to Swift. Can I use Realm the way I have it setup now. Or do I have to reconfigure the database to use the Realm Swift version as well? Does it not matter - simply use a bridging header like everything else or?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app conversion means actually deleting Objective-C code and putting Swift code in its place, then from an architectural standpoint, the best option would be to abandon the Objective-C API and go *full-Swift* with the Realm Swift framework instead.

Unlike the Objective-C bridging header, interacting with Realm via Realm Swift was redesigned to align to the best practices and ideals of writing Swift code, and so moving forward, you definitely should embrace that one.

If you've got users with pre-existing Realm database files that were created with Realm Objective-C, as long as you re-implement the model classes in Swift, with the same names (sadly, that would mean including any Objective-C prefixes at this point) and same ordering of properties, Realm Swift should be able to read them straight away.

Good luck! :)